# Is it possible to share SublimeText preferences *and* override one specific pref?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I share Sublime prefs between two machines (home, work) using Git.

My monitor at work has a higher DPI than my monitor at home, so in one of the two machines I'd like to override `font_size`.

I was hoping for:

- The possibility to override using a command-line flag (to do something like `subl --override-pref font_size=15`), like [kitty `--override`](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/invocation.html?highlight=override#cmdoption-kitty-override) does.
- Another level of prefs cascading below `User`.

, but I don't think any of this exists in Sublime. Language-specific config is not what I'm looking for, I want something global, but only in one of the two machines.

Ideas? Workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: My workaround is: i do not commit the preferences file and/or tell git to `.ignore` the preferences file.  This works well unless you update your preferences file often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general mechanism at play for settings files is that when Sublime loads a `sublime-settings` file by name, it pulls all of the similarly named files across all of the known packages and combines them together (the same also happens for many other resource files) with content from later files overriding anything that appears in an earlier file.

The [order that's imposed](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html) here is lexically by package, with `Default` always being first and `User` always being last. That's why the default settings are in the `Default` package and your custom settings are in the `User` package. Additionally syntax specific settings also apply (as do settings specific to projects).

Apart from this mechanism there's no direct way to override settings without some sort of manual intervention on your part. Potential solutions for this sort of problem include the following examples:

### Don't sync the `Preferences.sublime-settings` file

If the file isn't synced across multiple machines, then this problem becomes moot because each machine can easily have it's own unique settings. The downside to that is that each machine then has it's own unique settings, which is a pain in the butt if you often move from machine to machine and things don't quite work the same way.

### Use separate `git` branches

An alternative here if you're using `git` such as you are is to try and keep separate branches per host or per host type (like `hi_dpi` and `reg_dpi` or some such). Then on each machine check out the appropriate branch.

The obvious downsides here are having to try and cross-sync desired settings changes (for both `User` as well as any packages you might install) between branches, which is less than ideal unless you really love `git`.

### Use extra `Preferences.sublime-settings` files

Here the idea is that you don't include the `font_size` setting in your `User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file at all. Instead, you use `Browse Packages` from the command palette to open the `Packages` folder, then create a new folder there with some arbitrary name. Inside of that folder include a `Preferences.sublime-settings` file that contains only the `font_size` setting.

Doing this on multiple machines, you can sync the settings in your `User` folder across machines without also syncing the preference that contains the `font_size`. As a note, if you create the file while Sublime is already running, you may need to quit and restart to get it to notice that the settings file exists; this only applies the one time, though.

### Use a plugin

Looking at the link provided above, the ultimate trump card for any setting is a setting that's been applied directly to a `view`. Given that, you can use a plugin that selectively always applies a specific font size to any newly created or opened file:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

import socket


class CustomFontListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()

    def on_new(self, view):
        if self.hostname in ("host1", "host1.example.com", "host2"):
            view.settings().set("font_size", 20)

    on_load = on_new
```

Now any time you open a file or create a new buffer, if the current hostname is in the list you've configured the view will immediately get an appropriate `font_size` applied; otherwise the one from the preferences would be used instead.

You could also extend this to be configurable via it's own settings file, apply a different font size depending on the host name, etc.

Settings in views are persisted in the `sublime-session` file and also in the workspace files associated with `sublime-project` files, so these settings will remain in place even across restarts.

---

Something to keep in mind is that the internal commands for changing the font size (via `Preferences > Font` or via the mouse wheel keyboard shortcuts) work by writing a new `font_size` to your user preferences.

If you're using separate preference files, then doing this will add `font_size` to your `User` settings and you will need to manually remove it and modify the other settings file.

If you're using the plugin, then these shortcuts won't seem to do anything because it applies a `font_size` that overrides the `User` preference, but in fact as outlined above your preferences file end up being changed and you may not notice right away.

So whichever way you go, if you tend to use those you may need to make manual adjustments to settings files in the aftermath. It's also possible to create smarter versions of those commands as well, if this is the sort of thing that happens often.

Comment: *"Use extra `Preferences.sublime-settings` files"* makes total sense and is super elegant, I like it.  for the detailed answer (I won't need a plugin this time, but might another time) and the links to docs!

Comment: also, about *"If you're using separate preference files, then doing this will add font_size to your User settings and you will need to manually remove it and modify the other settings file"*: then I could reverse your suggestion: store & share all common settings in my custom Package, then store _only_ the font size in `User`, which then will be changeable locally by internal font size changes . Downside, of course: opening the prefs editor will fail to show me most of my prefs, as they're in the package.